# BorderLayout(); buttons not showing up

Tags: java, swing, border-layout

Hey guys my buttons and textarea will not display on JFrame when compiled, i have tried everything and searched this site but no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Due to them not letting me post without more detail i am just adding this part so i can hit the submit button.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class DataManager extends JFrame {

private String students[] = {"John Smith","Ken Hanson","Michael Li","John Andersen","Fiona Harris","Angela Lim","Bob London","Sydney Shield","Tina Gillard",
                             "Ross Brinns","Scott Cairns","Grant Peterson","David Power","Joshua Kane","Alan Newton","Frady Morgan","Quinn Perth"};


private int english[] = {80,52,71,61,39,62,31,46,60,26,77,40,58,38,94,90,97};

private int maths[] = {60,45,77,90,45,55,66,87,31,42,65,55,80,71,51,55,95};

private int total[];

private JButton sortNameButton;

private JButton sortTotalButton;

private JTextField searchTextField;

private JButton statisticsButton;

private JButton exitButton;

private JTextArea infoTextArea;

private JPanel jPan;


public DataManager() {

super("Data Manager ");

jPan = new JPanel();

sortNameButton = new JButton("Sort By Name");

sortTotalButton = new JButton("Sort By Total");

searchTextField = new JTextField("Search");

statisticsButton = new JButton("Statistics");

exitButton = new JButton("Exit");

infoTextArea = new JTextArea();

setLayout(new BorderLayout());

jPan.add(sortNameButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);
jPan.add(sortTotalButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);
jPan.add(searchTextField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
jPan.add(statisticsButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);
jPan.add(exitButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);
jPan.add(infoTextArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);


}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    DataManager frame = new DataManager();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(800,600);
    frame.setVisible(true);

} // End of main method.

} // End of DataManager class
```

Comment: add the JPanel lol, I made these silly mistakes when I was beginning to use Swing

Comment: haha yeh, im slowly understanding the little things.

Comment: Question rolled back. Please don't deface the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You add your JButtons to the jPan JPanel but never add the jPan to anything -- it must be added to your JFrame, to `this` to be seen.

```
jPan.add(sortNameButton);
jPan.add(sortTotalButton);
jPan.add(searchTextField);
jPan.add(statisticsButton);
jPan.add(exitButton);
jPan.add(infoTextArea);

add(jPan);  // don't forget this! ************
```

Note other problems:

- You set the JFrame's layout to BorderLayout -- it's **already** using BorderLayout
- You add components to your jPan JPanel with BorderLayout constants, but it's **not** using a BorderLayout.
- If it were, many buttons would not be seen since many are added to the *same* BorderLayout position and will cover the previous component added there.

In other words, read the tutorials as you're making wrong assumptions.

Better would be something like:

```
    // setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    jPan.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JPanel northPanel = new JPanel();  // **** to hold buttons

    northPanel.add(sortNameButton);
    northPanel.add(sortTotalButton);
    northPanel.add(searchTextField);
    northPanel.add(statisticsButton);
    northPanel.add(exitButton);

    jPan.add(northPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    jPan.add(infoTextArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: yes is it worked Thank you, something so little i should have picked up. really apprecaite it

Comment: yes i did i understand what you are saying thank you very much.